# Extract multiple parts of the same string and build URLs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to do 3 things with a string containing comma separated tags:

ex. tag1,tag2,tag3,player/2,tag5,player/4

1. Located one or more of the same tag within that string (in this case player/*)
2. Remove the 'player/' part
3. Build the int part to a URL for each instance within the string (ex. github.com/issues/*)

Any tips on doing this in Javascript or JQuery would be really helpful!

Comment: `var parts = String.split(",");` to split on the comma, then you can loop `parts` and do what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var data = 'tag1,tag2,tag3,player/2,tag5,player/4';
var dataArray = data.split(',');
for(var i = 0; i<dataArray.length; i++)
{
    if(dataArray[i].indexOf('player/') >= 0)
        {
            var url="github.com/issues/" + dataArray[i].substring(7);
            //do something with your url
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your problem,

You can split your string by commas, like this

```
var tagsArr = 'tag1,tag2,tag3,player/2,tag5,player/4'.split(',');
```

now tagsArr is the array of tags and comma seperated strings.

You can loop through the array and  remove the 'player/' by replacing with empty string
like this
`'player/2'.replace('player/','') // this will give you integer as you said`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method here.
How I'd do it is split the input, loop through split output, remove and construct url as I go.